# htaccess for separate folder without disturbing homepage

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have wordpress installed in rootfolder in `http://example.com` . I have created new folder named world `http://example.com/world` , I need htaccess to work on that particular folder alone , Is it possible?

My htaccess I need to use for folder world is given below. I added this in rootfolder htaccess and I got internal server error and hence I don't want to disturb the root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*)(\/?)$ / [QSA,NC,L]
```

My root folder htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Your root .htaccess already has WP rewrite rule isn't it? If yes post your complete `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Comment: @anubhava : hi sir i have updated.

Comment: Ok very good now you want to this folder `/world` independent of wordpress right?

Comment: You have to put your `.htaccess` file inside the `world` folder and it should work. If not, you have to add `AllowOverride All` option in your site configuration.

Comment: @anubhava : yes sir :)

Comment: @AnishaVirat: See my answer below and please don't call me "sir" :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` with this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# don't do anything for /world folder
RewriteRule ^world/ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Replace your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/world/.htaccess` with this code:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /world/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: hi , i have updated now http://domain.com/world/anythingrandom.php must point to http://domain.com/world/index.php . why it is showing not found url of wordpress

Comment: check the updated code for `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess and world/.htaccess`

Comment: thanks working perfect :) i see you are the one answering all the .htaccess questions..where did u learn this ? do you have good tutorial link ?

Comment: lol :) No haven't see any complete tutorial on mod_rewrite. I am not even on admin side, just learnt it because of my inherent interest in regex. Q&A on this site are best set of knowledge-base for this.

Comment: lol :) Q&A in this site .htaccess tag is always has your answer :D

Comment: There are other knowledgeable experts also, I still have a long way to go. Though its real fun solving complex problems and helping the community.